# Android crash on having reference to/ implementing interface

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android coming from a Java background. So excuse me if this is a really simple fix. I created a machine emulator in java and I wanted to run it on Android with a simple UI. The problem is that it crashes when I do this

```
 public class UITerminal extends EditText implements Terminal
```

I also tried this inside the class

```
 Terminal terminal;
 public void init()
 {
      terminal = new Terminal()
      {
         //implemented methods
      }
 }
```

both of these solutions crashed upon opening. Any suggestions on how I should be doing this? Thanks in advance. This is my first Android experience.

EDIT

I click on the app and it shows "Unfortunately MyTronEmulator has stopped working"

```
10-12 09:27:58.187: I/dalvikvm(964): Failed resolving Ldavis/mytronemulator/UITerminal; interface 635 'Ldavis/lib/mytronemulator/Terminal;'
10-12 09:27:58.187: W/dalvikvm(964): Link of class 'Ldavis/mytronemulator/UITerminal;' failed
10-12 09:27:58.227: D/AndroidRuntime(964): Shutting down VM
10-12 09:27:58.227: W/dalvikvm(964): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{davis.mytronemulator/davis.mytronemulator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class davis.mytronemulator.UITerminal
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class davis.mytronemulator.UITerminal
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at davis.mytronemulator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  ... 11 more
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "davis.mytronemulator.UITerminal" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/davis.mytronemulator-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/davis.mytronemulator-2, /system/lib]]
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
10-12 09:27:58.347: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  ... 21 more
```

Comment: post the logcat of the crash

Comment: Which is the 'crash'?

Comment: I added the .jar file as a library and it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a while back, but I was trying to use a Java 1.7 lib. Android only supports up to 1.6
I wish the errors would just say that :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your IDE is exporting the .jar file, on top of adding it as a library. Otherwise it is assumed that it is on the phone/emulator already.

In eclipse you can make sure this is done by right clicking the project -> build path -> configure build path -> Order and Export -> check the library.

Comment: I did do that. I added the library under the lib folder and then added the jar as a file and checked the box in Order and Export.

Comment: @TylerDavis have you tried cleaning (Project->clean) the projects and re-building?

Comment: Although I do believe that my problem is that the jar is not getting exported to the emulator